# How to find date difference when using Angular UI datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the AngularUI datepicker given in  http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

I have two datepickers in my page and on click of a button need to validate if the date difference between the two values is greater than 12 months.
I have not found any method which can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/CeZrzGqD90cvaMLER6R5?p=preview
I've made consumption that year has 365 days.

```
 angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    var DatepickerDemoCtrl = function($scope) {

      $scope.open = function($event, opened) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();

        $scope[opened] = true;
      };

      $scope.dateOptions = {
        formatYear: 'yy',
        startingDay: 1
      };


function yearDiff(first, second) {
  if(second && first){
    return (second-first)/(1000*60*60*24*365);
  }
  else
  {
    return 0;

  }
}

    $scope.$watch('start', function(i){
     $scope.diff =  yearDiff($scope.start, $scope.end)
      console.log($scope.diff);
    });
    $scope.$watch('end', function(i){
     $scope.diff =  yearDiff($scope.start, $scope.end)
      console.log($scope.diff);
    });


      $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
      $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
    };
```

Comment: thanks for the code! the second-first throws gives a NaN when I implement the same in my code!

Comment: This way worked! my problem was my date was a string. So I did a new Date(mystring) and then followed your code. Thank you